# How i can select one single data with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I was building a simple student management system where i want that when students are logged in so they can see their personal details like name, email, phone number etc in that partiicular student login. So how can i  select one single data of the student from the database.

```
<?php 
  include "dbconfig.php";
  $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM new_student"); ?>
<div class="user-details-box">
    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="info-table table-responsive">
            <table class="table text-nowrap">
                <tbody>
                  <?php
                    $sl =0;
                    while($sql_fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { ?>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Student ID:</td>
                      <td class="font-medium text-dark-medium"><?php 
                      echo $sql_fetch['id']; ?></td>
                      ?>
```

Comment: This is not really a PHP question, it is a MySQL question. Your SQL query ("SELECT * FROM...") will need to include a "WHERE" clause so that you can specify the user for whom you wish to pull data. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can select a single data from the database just change your query to

```
SELECT * FROM new_student LIMIT 1
```

And just one row or all the details of a single students will be fetched.

Comment: Ermmm.. this will just be the first random student, you would need something like a `WHERE` clause to fetch a particular students details.